# Does occur any boxing/unboxing in this code?

Tags: java, boxing, autoboxing

Given the following code, does the Java compiler apply any boxing/unboxing this case?

```
public static Integer sum(Iterable<Integer> numbers){
    Integer sum = 0;
    for(Integer n : numbers){
        sum += n;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Do you need any Fürther explanation or is my answer what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

Here the int 0 is auto-boxed to an Integer sum:

```
Integer sum = 0;
```

Here the values are unboxed as the unary plus operator only applies to int:

```
sum += n;
```

Here no unboxing happens as you iterate over Integers:

```
for(Integer n : numbers)
```

Unboxing in a for loop can happen if you do (e.g.):

```
for(int n : numbers)
```

See [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for very similar examples and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Integer` object is converted into `int` literal while performing the addition with `+` operator. Have a look at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). It says the following:

> Because the remainder (%) and unary plus (+=) operators do not apply
>   to Integer objects, you may wonder why the Java compiler compiles the
>   method without issuing any errors. The compiler does not generate an
>   error because it invokes the intValue method to convert an Integer to
>   an int at runtime.

Comment: Yes it compiles